# Matrix inversion of an analytical function

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, integral-equations

Following problem:

I have a function

$f(x_1,x_2)$

and Im looking for the inverse $finv(x_1,x_2)$ of the function which is defined through:

$\int f(x_1,y)\cdot finv(y,x_2) d y =\delta(x_1,x_2) $

where $\delta(x_1,x_2) $ is the Dirac delta function.

When I'm trying to discretize $f$ and then to invert as usual matrix I get numerically bad results. I mean the result is ok, but I need extremely fine discretization.

I'm sure there should be some other method than the poor man inversion. Something like inversion with weights or similar.

Probably there exist already a c++ library for such problem.

Comment: Probably this question is more suitable on scicomp.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

In case your $f$ is a function only of $x_1-x_2$ and limits of integration are $-\infty$ to $+\infty $ then a solution via Fourier transform method can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation).